# Capacitor in the circuit - Bypass capacitor

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, current-measurement, bypass

I was trying to measure the supply current of a CAN transceiver during fault conditions, one thing which I noticed was that during CANH to GND(when the current consumption is supposed to be the highest), the current was kind of like a sine wave and going negative during '1' bit transmission(recessive state). 
Below is the circuit, 
[image]

R410 was unmounted and current was measured at Vcc. When I unmounted the bypass capacitor C405 (470nF), I noticed that the current waveform as expected, as in was not going negative during '1' bit trasmission.

Waveform with capacitor :The yellow and pink signals are CANH and CANL signals, the green is the TXD signal from the function generator, the blue signal is the current signal and the last signal is the 'CANH-CANL' difference signal.
[image]
Waveform without capacitor:The green is the current signal, blue is the CANH signal, pink and blue are RXD and TXD signals respectively.
[image]

I understand that the capacitor was trying to filter and hence the waveform was not a square waveform, but could someone please elaborate , I'm trying to understand why the current is going negative ? (the CAN transceiver is being powered by a 5V regulator, CAN supply current going negative means that the current is being sinked to the 5V regulator ?Is that possible? or is the current flowing through the output capacitor of the 5V regulator be a possibility?)

EDIT :
1)Waveform with 100nF bypass capacitor at the supply pin of the CAN transceiver.
  Yellow is the signal from the function generator, blue is CANH, pink is CANL, 
  green is the CAN current.
[image]

2)Waveform - normal operation(without the short of CANH to GND) 
Yellow is the signal from the function generator, blue is CANH, pink is CANL, 
  green is the CAN current.
[image]

Comment: Looks like the capacitor is resonating with some inductance. Try using 100nF and check if the frequency has been changed

Comment: BTW, i assumed the blue trace on the scope image was the current, but please update your original post with an explanation of the signals of both scope images

Comment: @Huisman  have updates the signals, thanks for the suggestion. I'm sorry I didn't quite understand how the 100nF could solve the problem ? and could you please tell me which frequency  you are talking about ?

Comment: Is CANH is both screen shots zero?

Comment: It will not solve the problem (only when lucky), but it helps deducing the cause. In the high period of of the green TXD signal, the blue current signal looks like a sine with higher harmonics. Check if that shape hanges with 100nF

Comment: Taking a closer look at both screen shots on a PC now. What's happening to CANH? It looks the same (and equally worse) with and without capacitor. I think you should focus on that.

Comment: Yeah CANH is being short to GND in both the cases.

Comment: My apologies for forgetting the first part of your original post. I was confused by the remark *"how the 100nF could solve the problem?"* Not shorting CANH would *solve* the problem. But still, to understand what's happening when CANH is shorted, I still recommend trying a 100nF cap and compare the results.

Comment: @Huisman Hello, I checked with 100nF , please look at the edit above, I couldn't attach the oscilloscope capture here.